# How to use Left function with MS Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Alright, I am attempting to use a basic left() function with a MS Access query, in order to create an inner join between two tables. The two columns that will be joined contain the first 3 character of a given street address.

I have attempted to use the function as shown:
[image]

I simply want to take the first 3 characters (from the left obviously) of this column, and join it to the "Left 3 of adress" column in my Branch Management sheet. Every time I attempt to run this query however, I get a syntax error. The left function is pretty straightforward in almost every language/RDBMS, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: here is a screen shot of the error:
[image]
The error is wonderfully vague.

Comment: Are `[Branch Mgmt]` and `[SalesPage Offices w/CRD]` queries?  Do both of those queries run without any errors?

Comment: `[Branch Mgmt]` is a linked Excel table. `[SalesPage Offices w/CRD]` is a query, and it runs fine. It's a standard query that use on a daily basis.

Comment: Can you share the syntax error?  I just tested a query using `LEFT` on a join in Access and it worked fine for me.

Comment: When you select Tools->References from the VB Editor's main menu, are any of the checked references marked "MISSING"?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the error to my OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You left out a close parenthesis.  Change this ...

```sql
ON ([Branch Mgmt].[Left 3 of address] = left([SalesPage Offices w/CRD].ADDRESS_LINE_1,3)
```

to this ...

```sql
ON ([Branch Mgmt].[Left 3 of address] = left([SalesPage Offices w/CRD].ADDRESS_LINE_1,3))
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked great. I missed a simple piece of the puzzle. Sure wish that Access had intelliSense like SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use the `LEFT()` function in your join statement.  Instead run a sub query to get the field you want and then link them together.  Something like the following:

```
SELECT M.TRADE_FIRM, M.POSTAL_CODE_1, M.ADDRESS_LINE_1, 
       M.OFFICE_ID, M.STATE_PROVINCE, M.CITY, B.*
FROM
(
  SELECT S.*, LEFT(S.ADDRESS_LINE_1, 3) AS Left3Addr
  FROM [SalesPage Offices w/CRD] AS S
) AS M
INNER JOIN [Branch Mgmt] AS B ON B.[Left 3 of address] = M.Left3Addr
AND B.State = M.State
AND B.City = M.City
WHERE M.TRADE_FIRM = 'WHATEVER'
```

Comment: Thank you for the respnse, but I prefer to use the function. My fear is that a subquery would slow down my Access DB considerably in this case, since I am constantly working with very large data sets from the back end of a large SQL Database.